# Openlayers: feature.get returns the attributes path

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an openlayers map with a point layer that on click on a feature opens a popup. Inside the popup I show a clickable link that is supposed to lead to a url that is stored inside the attribute table of the layer.

But if I click the layer a link opens to a path like "C:/Users/user/.../URL". The URL is all I want to have, but the browser also opens the path to where the project is saved.

My code:

```
map.on('click', function(event) {
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    if (layer === knoten) {
        return feature;
    }
});
if (feature != null) {
    var pixel = event.pixel;
    var coord = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(pixel);
    popup.setPosition(coord);
    $(elementPopup).attr('data-content', '<b>1: </b>' + '&ensp;' + feature.get('ERHEB_NR') +
        '</br><b>2: </b>' + '&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '<a id="link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Link</a>');
    $(elementPopup).popover({'placement': 'top', 'html': true});
    $(elementPopup).popover('show');

    document.getElementById('link').href = feature.get('KATASTER')
}
else {
    $(elementPopup).popover({'html': true});
    $(elementPopup).popover('hide');
}
});
```

If I substitute `'<a id="link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Link</a>'` for `feature.get('KATASTER')` the correct link appears (but since since it is not inside the  statement it is not clickable).

Answer (score 0):

What about intializing the popever with the `content` option, instead updating only the link?

```
map.on('click', function(event) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        if (layer === knoten) {
            return feature;
        }
    });
    // Always hide the popover
    $(elementPopup).popover('hide');
    if (feature != null) {
        var pixel = event.pixel;
        var coord = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(pixel);
        popup.setPosition(coord);

        $(elementPopup).popover({
           placement: 'top',
           animation: false,
           html: true,
           trigger: 'focus',
           title: "",
           content: '<b>1: </b>' + '&ensp;' + feature.get('ERHEB_NR') +
    '</br><b>2: </b>' + '&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '<a id="link" target="_blank" href="'+feature.get('KATASTER')+'" rel="noopener noreferrer">Link</a>'
        });
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about the content option yet, thats definetly a cleaner way to do it, thanks! But still, I get the same as before: Not the url appears in the new browser window, but the path to the project with the url appended shows up.

Comment: ups. i didn't get the question then. what's inside `feature.get('KATASTER')` then?

Comment: I have a layer with an attribute called KATASTER and the KATASTER holds a link for each feature. So with the `feature.get('KATASTER')` request I am supposed to get back a link. But what I get is the path where the code is saved with the url appended like "C:/Users/user/.../URL", if the project is saved in "C:/Users/user/...". I don't have the problem if I just use `feature.get('KATASTER')` without the `<a href ...>`. I just get the unclickable url, but I need a clickable one. I was probably unclear in my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: so if you print out the first `feature.get('KATASTER')` what are you getting? if it's `C:/Users/user/.../URL` the problema is where you're assigning `KATASTER`, so that's why will be usefull to see your feature declaration to find out the problem.

Comment: If I print out ´feature.get('KATASTER')´ I get the url without the path. So I assume it has to do with the creation of a link out of it.

Comment: starting with `/` or `.` ? what's the url of the page you're loading?

Comment: The url starts with ´www´ and that seems to be the problem. If I add ´http://´ everything works fine. I see that it is needed, so the browser recognizes the string as an url.